# Newton's method has local quadratic convergence. which method is the best to start from?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization, newton-raphson

Newton's method has *local* quadratic convergence. Is there a good method that I can run for a few iteration to get a better domain to start from?

Comment: There is no general method for the global solution of nonlinear equations.

Comment: some method that you can mention that are good in some cases? Just for the few first iterations.

Comment: There are good root separation methods for polynomials. Nothing for the general case.

Comment: Also you should take into account that Newton's method doesn't have quadratic convergence when the presented equation has multiple roots, though you can recover original convergence by applying some methods. You have Steffensen's method and Muller's method which are quadratic convergence methods.

Comment: Are they quadratic in case of multiply roots also? What are you recommending to use from all of them (Newton\ Steffensen\ Muller)?
Thanks again!

Comment: It would improve the Question to specify details of the function you want to optimize and/or find roots of.  The one-variable case is much easier to analyze.  There are many approaches to multivariable function optimization which are more robust than direct application of Newton-Raphson/steepest ascent.  Without more context it is guesswork to supply details of one method or another.

Answer (score 2):

Because your post is tagged optimization, it is not clear whether you mean Newton's method to identify a root or Newton's method to identify a local minimum (or more generally, a stationary point).

If you mean to identify a root of a system of equations $F(x) = 0$, where $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$, one way to globalize Newton's method is to formulate the problem as the optimization problem
$$
  \min_x \ f(x) \quad \text{where} \quad f(x) := \tfrac{1}{2} \|F(x)\|^2,
$$
and where
$$
  F(x) =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    f_1(x) \\
    \dots  \\
    f_m(x)
  \end{bmatrix},
  \qquad
  \|F(x)\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^m f_i(x)^2.
$$
Now the gradient and Hessian of $f$ can be computed in terms of $F$:
$$
  \nabla f(x) = J(x)^T F(x), \qquad
  \nabla^2 f(x) = J(x)^T J(x) + \sum_{i=1}^m f_i(x) \nabla^2 f_i(x),
$$
where $J$ is the Jacobian of $F$, i.e., the matrix whose $i$-th row is $\nabla f_i(x)^T$.

You can apply Newton's method to $f$ and globalize it using a linesearch, e.g., an Armijo linesearch. The procedure is as follows:

1. At $x_k$ compute Newton's direction by solving $\nabla^2 f(x_k) d_k = -\nabla f(x_k)$. Because of the form of $\nabla^2 f(x_k)$, it may be necessary to modify it to ensure that $d_k$ is a descent direction. Locally, assuming you are close to a minimizer, it shouldn't be necessary to modify.
2. Compute a step size $t \in (0, 1]$ such that
   $$
   f(x_k + t d_k) \leq f(x_k) + \alpha t \nabla f(x_k)^T d_k
   $$
   starting from $t=1$ and halving $t$ until the inequality is satisfied. If $d_k$ is a descent direction, this procedure is guaranteed to succeed.
3. Set $x_{k+1} = x_k + t d_k$.

The advantage of this approach is that if you converge to a minimizer where $\nabla^2 f$ is positive definite, you retain Newton's quadratic convergence locally. That is because you can guarantee that $t=1$ at all iterations asymptotically.

The drawback of this approach is that you may converge to a stationary point $x^*$ of $f$ (perhaps even a minimizer) where $F(x) \not = 0$. This can only happen if $J(x^*)$ is rank deficient. If you can ensure that $J$ always has full rank, the procedure is sound. If not and you hit a spurious solution, one workaround is to start the minimization from another initial guess. Another workaround is to apply a deflation technique to remove this minimizer from the problem.

If you were talking about Newton's method for optimization, the procedure is identical except that you would use the objective $f$ defined in your problem.

Most optimization methods are local in nature and must be globalized using a linesearch. There exist other globalization methods (trust regions, homotopy, $\dots$) but the idea is the same.